# Adding rank column based on other numeric column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm experiencing trouble with creating a new rank column. I have the following data:

```
Title             Cat. Rank     
The Da Vinci Code Book 19
The Da Vinci Code Book 19
The Da Vinci Code Book 19
Sisterhood....    Book 21
Book X            Book 34
Book X            Book 34
```

I need to create a new rank column based on the current rank column where Da Vinci code gets a 1 in all rows with da vinci code. When a new title appears the rank should change to a 2 etc.

I've been trying a lot of variations of rank, e.g.:

```
  dt.reviews.books.new[,sales_rank_cat:=rank(title, ties.method="first"),by=title]
```

But this assigns a 1 to every title.

Comment: Try something like `dt.reviews.books.new[, sales_rank_cat := .GRP, by = title]`

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are saying DaVinci Code will always receive 1 and the others are already in rank order such that the following titles will receive 2, 3, ....n.

```
library(data.table)
newDF <- data.table(dt.reviews.books.new) %>%
         newDF[, newRank := 1:.N, by = "Title"]
```

Again and with warning, this ranking assumes your Titles are currently in rank-order. If your new ranking is based on the current rank I would use `sort()` or `arrange()` to order by `Rank`.

Comment: newDF <- data.table(dt.reviews.books.new) %>%
  newDF[, newRank := 1:.N, by = "title"]   I get the following error: Error in `[.data.table`(., newDF, , `:=`(newRank, 1:.N), by = "title") : 
  Provide either 'by' or 'keyby' but not both

Comment: And the titles are indeed already in rank order!

Comment: The pipe here is completely irrelevant/confusing/unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank((rank)))
```

if there's a meaning to the rank number you can use `desc`:

```
df %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(rank)))
```